# Spark shell doesn't expand variables of Hadoop configuration

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, configuration-files

In Hadoop, I can use variable in configuration files and Hadoop will expand it using existing key or the `-Dvariable_name=value` of `HADOOP_OPTS`.

For example, given an `core-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>${fs.defaultFS}</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

When starting HDFS, I set an environment variable `HADOOP_OPTS=-Dfs.defaultFS=<value>` and Hadoop will expand these variables in `core-site.xml` using options in `HADOOP_OPTS`.

In Spark shell, it doesn't expand the variables but using their literal value `${fs.defaultFS}`.

```
...
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: hdfs://${fs.defaultFS}
  at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
  ... 66 more
```

How can I make Spark expands Hadoop configuration variables?

Comment: I've closed your question yesterday because I've considered a duplicate, if it's not the case, please don't delete and post the same question again but edit your [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53853751/spark-shell-doesnt-expand-variables-of-hadoop-configuration) explaining why the link provided doesn't help you answer your question.

Comment: I think for these properties, it's better to just make the XML files and export `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`